# Adding different metricies in grafana from prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have different metrices in prometheus `counter_metrics a`, `couneter_metrices b` and I want a singlestat for the count of all the different request metrics.

How am I able to fetch this?

```
(sum(couneter_metrics{instance="a,job="b"}))+
```

Comment: Do you mean you have a metric `couneter_metrics` with different labels that you want to sum? Or that you have two metrics `couneter_metricsA` and `couneter_metricsB` that you want to sum together?

Comment: i have two metrices couneter_metricesA and couneter_metricesB I need to sum the metrices

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the singlestat panel, you can just sum the two metrics and then add them together. Here is an example with two different metrics:

`sum(prometheus_local_storage_memory_series) + sum(counters_logins)`

Recommended reading, just in case you are doing anything with rates as well: https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate/

Comment: I am facing an issue while doing these like sum(prometheus_local_storage_memory_series) + sum(counters_logins) is giving 0 value but if I try each one individually its displaying results.Can u suggest me where I am misleading

Comment: Sounds very strange - it is just simple addition as far as I know. Can you show your query (you can change the metric names if they are private data) . Are you able to edit your question and add the query there?

Comment: sum(counter_http_a)+
sum(counter_http_b)+
sum(counter_http_c) these 3 metrices are giving right values sum(counter_http_d) i am adding i am getting 0 as i check in prometheus the above three metrices has value of 1 week but for the 4th it has value of 2week so i changed the time in grafana for 30 days back still i get null